# Identity Server logs clean-up

Tags: identity-server, logging

Is there any way to clean-up logs for Sitecore 9.3 Identity Server?

I searched for logging configuration but didn't find any. I want to update configuration so that it automatically deletes logs older than 10 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identity Server uses **Serilog** (https://github.com/serilog/serilog)  for writing logs and a single file sink is configured by default.

Which retains 31 files (for one month) by default. If you want to retain only 10 days log then pass `retainedFileCountLimit` argument with value set to 10 in `<IS Siteroot>\sitecorehost.xml` as shown below

[image]

**References** -

1. https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/en/logging.html
2. https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file#limits

Comment: added a second answer after reading this - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice

Comment: thank you. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Great !! you saved my day !!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do at Sitecore level only then you can add entry for IdentityServer log folder in `<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.CleanupAgent"` of CM website  but make sure you give delete access to IIS AppPool user e.g. - `IIS AppPool\CMSiteAppPoolUser`

```
<remove folder="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc93identityserver.dev.local\logs" pattern="*.*" maxAge="10.00:00:00"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that it should be done not on the Sitecore level.

I do the similar thing by scheduled PowerShell script.
For your case this Powershell script should do the work:

```
$old = 10
$folder = 'your path'
Get-ChildItem $folder | Where-Object {-not $_.PSIsContainer -and $now.Subtract($_.CreationTime).Days -gt $old } | ForEach-Object {Remove-Item $_.FullName -Confirm:$false -Force -Recurse}
```

Then you need to add execution of this script to Windows scheduler if you work with on-premise hosting or use [WebJobs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create) if you use Azure PaaS.